# PHP mysqli_fetch_assoc() Function returning NULL while the same PHP file works

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli, null

i have spent a day now but i am not able to solve the following problem.
I have this code to access my database and i want to get some values.
The weird thing is, that the same code works for the same php file on the same server in the same directory.
I wanted to create a new php file with a different sql selection, but this one always returns null instead of a json array.

Any helpful advice would be great!
I am running a wordpress site, maybe thats an important information.

```
<?php
if( isset( $_POST[user_id] ) )
{
    $user_id = $_POST[user_id];

    $servername = "****";
    $username = "****";
    $password = "****";
    $dbname = "****";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    //echo "Connected successfully";
    //echo $user_id;


    $sql = "SELECT *
    FROM felderkonfig
    WHERE felderkonfig_user_id = '$user_id' ";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);    //sql abfrage in array speichern
    $myArray = array();
    $myArray =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);  //umwandeln in assoziatives array

    echo json_encode($myArray);     //echo als json array


    $conn->close();
    exit(); 
}else{
    echo "Fehler bei if isset";     
}
?>
```

Comment: Just for starters, $user_id should not be enclosed in single apostrophes. It wil make it literal used that way in a string.

Comment: Your query is prone to SQL injections. You should learn about [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Now for the error you're getting, it either means your query has an error (but you should see a PHP warning, due to `$result` being false), or it doesn't return any row.

Comment: suggest you to `var_dump` you query and then execute that in your database invironment and check if you have result or not.

Comment: Hi guys. Thanks a lot for the quick replies. I have already tried different queries. Also directly in my database and they work fine. As i mentioned above, exactly the same code & query works fine and that confuses me a lot.

Comment: do you get `Fehler bei if isset` message too or not?

Comment: are you sure `user_id` has been passed to your code?

Comment: no i am not getting the efhler bei if isset message. "Echo connected successfully" does work. I again checked the sql with var dump in php my admin and i got results.

Comment: Put 'echo $sql;' after assigning it. That will check if the id is being added to the sql statement. NEver mind phpmyadmin, it's a different kettle of fish.

Comment: Hi there. I don't know why but it works now. The final code is posted below. Can someone tell me how i would have to write the code to make it safe to SQL injections with prepared statements? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should include this file to the prefered php file like where ever you want to connect the database

```
<?php include 'connect.php' ?>
```

in connect.php file should have the connection settings like what you metioned in the question exluded selct query

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the advice but what is the advantage if i am going to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I dont' know why but the code is working know. The behaviour was quite weird, maybe there were some server-side problems, but i don't know. It would be great if someone coulde tell me how i can make the folllwing code safer. Thanks a lot.

```
<?php
if( isset( $_POST[virtuellesdepot_id] ) )
{
    $virtuellesdepot_id = $_POST[virtuellesdepot_id];

    $servername = "****";
    $username = "****";
    $password = "****";
    $dbname = "****";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    //echo "Connected successfully";

    //echo $user_id;


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM virtuelledepots ";   

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);    //sql abfrage in array speichern
    $myArray = array();
    $myArray = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); //umwandeln in assoziatives array


    echo json_encode($myArray);     //echo als json array


    $conn->close();
    exit(); 
}else{
    echo "Fehler bei if isset"; 
}
?>
```

Comment: Your $sql is most certainly not the same as the first one.

Comment: i know. But the sql now is much bigger and quite different. It wasn't a problem by the sql statement.